# how add css class to product boxes li, for img, add cart button, decs, price…

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

please if you could help.

I have differect resolution and aspect ratio of images uploaded to product. When i see product list:

http://kachliar.sk/obchod/page/4

products boxes are not same, i would like all images are fit to cell width, need "add to cart" button in same line for all product boxes ...atc all i can manage via css classes,

but my problem is how i can add class to that elements inside

tag.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add class to those elements. You can apply CSS style to those elements by using following selectors respectively.

```
.post-type-archive-product  ul.products li.product
.post-type-archive-product  ul.products li img
.post-type-archive-product  ul.products li .button
.post-type-archive-product  ul.products li .woocommerce-loop-product__title
.post-type-archive-product  ul.products li span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works, please i am now able to make all images same, changing colors of any elemetn... But i am still not able to put button to baseline - bottom of <li>  i mean, this not fork for me:   vertical-align: bottom; It is really new for me without div, but slowly getting in. Could you hint me with this problem?

Comment: Use below CSS code to align buttons to bottom.

.post-type-archive-product ul.products li .button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

Comment: thanks for a lesson! works like a charm. Hope i will be able manage rest.